# After adding user to ArrayList he's without [] and using other function he's with [] Java

Tags: java

After I try to add user to my file with one function he appears there without [], but after I try to use another function the content is with []. They both are

After first function:

> Programuotojo vardas: W, pavarde: X, amzius: 2, programavimo kalba: C

After another:

> [Programuotojo vardas: Petras, pavarde: Petraitis, amzius: 21,
>   programavimo kalba: C#]

This is my first function.

```
 else {
            System.out.println("Laikinu darbuotoju sarasas");
            for (int i = 0; i < darbuotojuArrayList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("ID: " + "[" + i + "]" + " " + darbuotojuArrayList.get(i));
            }
            File FILE = new File(darbuotojuFailas);
            try {
                System.out.println("Issirinkite pagal ID darbuotoja kuri pridesite i sarasa");
                Scanner SI = new Scanner(System.in);
                int vartotojoPasirinkimasKuriPridetiISistema = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
                BufferedWriter file = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILE, true));
                file.write(darbuotojuArrayList.get(vartotojoPasirinkimasKuriPridetiISistema).toString());
                file.newLine();
                file.close();
                System.out.println("darbuotojas issaugotas sistemoje");
                pasirinkimaiSuDarbuotojais();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage() + "problema su darbuotoju failu");
            }
        }
```

And the second

```
private void vartotojasPridedamasISistemaIsRandom() {
    File FILE = new File(darbuotojuFailasSuRandom);
    // cia kai yra failas ir jis nera tuscias
    if (FILE.exists() && FILE.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Pasirinkite viena darbuotoja is pateiktu variantu, kuris bus pridetas i sistema");
        try {
            Scanner SC = new Scanner(FILE);
            for (int i = 0; i < FILE.length(); i++) {
                if (SC.hasNextLine()) {
                    String parodymui = SC.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("ID: " + "[" + i + "]" + " " + parodymui);
                }
            }
            Scanner SI = new Scanner(System.in);
            int vartotojoPasirinkimasPerkeliantISistema = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
            String line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(darbuotojuFailasSuRandom)).get(vartotojoPasirinkimasPerkeliantISistema);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":([^,\\]]*)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            String[] output = new String[4];
            int i = 0;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                output[i++] = matcher.group(1).trim().replace(",", ", ");
            }
            // Cia kai vartotojas pasirenka perkelti i sistema programuotoja
            if (vartotojoPasirinkimasPerkeliantISistema == 0) {
                darbuotojuArrayList.add(new Programuotojas(output[0], output[1], Integer.parseInt(output[2]), output[3]));
                File file = new File(darbuotojuFailas);
                BufferedWriter files = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
                files.write(darbuotojuArrayList.toString());
                files.newLine();
                files.close();
            }
            // Cia kai vartotojas pasirenka perkelti i sistema testuotoja
            else {
                darbuotojuArrayList.add(new Testuotojas(output[0], output[1], Integer.parseInt(output[2]), Integer.parseInt(output[3])));
                File file = new File(darbuotojuFailas);
                BufferedWriter files = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
                files.write(darbuotojuArrayList.toString());
                files.newLine();
                files.close();
            }
            System.out.println("Sekmingai perkeltas darbuotojas i sistema");
            pasirinkimaiSuDarbuotojais();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "problema su random darbuotoju failu");
        }
    }
    // cia kai nera arba failas tuscias butu
    else {
        try {
            BufferedWriter file = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILE, true));
            file.write("Programuotojo vardas: Petras, pavarde: Petraitis, amzius: 21, programavimo kalba: C#");
            file.newLine();
            file.write("Testuotojo vardas: Jonas, pavarde: Jonaitis, amzius: 20, isdirbtos valandos: 6000");
            file.close();
            vartotojasPridedamasISistemaIsRandom();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage() + "problema su random darbuotoju failu");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that every ArrayList element have to be with [], but why with first code there are no []?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: After I used the first function why there are no [], but after I use the second one there are

Comment: Ok I think I understand now and the answer from Brady looks right.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function you are using a get before you call the toString method and the second method you are not.

My apologies if this is not the issue, the language barrier was throwing me through some hoops reading the code (*face palm* on my part)...

Comment: Next time I post here code I will try to change everything to text to english language

Comment: @HenrikasB Don't do so for my case, I've seen many questions in another language get answered by english speakers, I just had a little extra trouble following variables around your code, that's all :)